# Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT> in unaltered WooCommerce code

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce

The code below is a part of WooCommerce.

```
<ul id="shipping_method" class="woocommerce-shipping-methods">
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_table_rate9" value="table_rate:9" class="shipping_method">
    <label for="shipping_method_0_table_rate9">Table Rate: 
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>135.00</bdi>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the checkout screen, I get the following console error.

> Incorrect use of  The label's for attribute
> doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from
> correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working
> correctly.

The referenced line is line 4 (`<label for="shipping_method_0_table_rate9">`). I'm not sure what to fix here since the `for` attribute exists in the line above.

Comment: Yes, your label's `for` points to the ID of an existing input field - but that field is of type `hidden`, so having a label for it does not make much sense to begin with. (Clicking on the label is supposed to focus the input field - which is not possible with a _hidden_ field.)

Comment: This slightly defective HTML code is probably generated by a theme. It's nothing to worry about in production.